# PHP Multiple Submit Buttons in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, form-submit

I have been creting a php website that allows users to add comments to an image that is within the system.

The way my code currently works is that it gets all of the comments for that image and places them into a table using a while loop:

```
$commResult = mysql_query("SELECT u.userID, u.USERNAME, c.COMMENT, c.DATE_ADDED, c.ACTIVE, c.id FROM USERS u, COMMENTS c WHERE u.id = c.user_id and c.box_id = $boxId ORDER BY c.DATE_ADDED DESC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($commResult))
    {
        if ($row[4] != 0)
        {
            echo "<tr><td><a href='User.php?uid=$row[0]'>$row[1]</a></td>";
            echo "<td style='text-align:right;'>" . date("d M y g:iA", strtotime($row[3])) ;
            if (isLoggedIn())
                echo " - DELETE";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>" . $row[2] . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

The problem i am having is that i would like to put a submit button where the word DELETE is. This would create a button for each comment row and therefore if clicked the code would not know what button has been pressed. Is there anyway to get arround this so each button has a individual ID so when the code is submitted it knows what the id of the comment is and therefore i am able to process a delete on the database table for that comment ID.

I have tried adding this piece of code where the word DELETE is:

```
if (isLoggedIn())
                echo " - <button type='submit' name='delCom_sub' value='$row[5]' >X</button>";
```

However when i try to handle the button click using the following code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['delCom_sub']))
{
    echo "test";
}
```

IF i click a button the word "test" is never displayed.

Comment: why not use the commentID for the button specific to that comment?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code. I have tried doing this and its not working. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @ashley I have added the code i tried to my origional post.

Comment: for example, your button would look like `<input type="submit" id="'.$row['commentID'].'">`

Comment: @ashley And how would i handle the request when the button is clicked?

Comment: @GlenRobson have you seen my answer, I've given two examples.

Comment: sorry, I'm used to using jQuery of sending data. It will have to be the `name` attribute you set the ID to. or have a look at MrCodes examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a separate form for each comment row. The ID of the comment is stored in a hidden field. Using this method you need to remove any parent form to prevent nested forms.

```
        if (isLoggedIn())
        {
            echo '<form action="delete.php" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . (int)$row['id'] . '" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                  </form>';
        }
```

On the page that you post to, ie `delete.php`:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isLoggedIn())
{
    // do the delete with $_POST['id']
}
```

Other than that, you could do it with Javascript by populating a hidden field when a button is clicked. Another option would be to store the comment ID in a submit button's `name` attribute, doing that you would have to loop over the post variables and parse out the ID.

Example using the button `name`:

```
if (isLoggedIn())
            echo " - <input type='submit' name='delete_" . (int)$row['id'] . "' value='Delete' />";
```

On the receiving page:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isLoggedIn())
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if(strpos($key, 'delete_') === 0)
        {
            $id = substr($key, 7);
            // do the delete for $id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply MrCode, however both these techniques seem very extensive. Is there no way to have the buttons with the same name but with a different ID. Then when we handle the submit of the button i can place the ID into a vairable?

Comment: The submit button's `id` is not transmitted to the server, only its `name` and `value`, therefore for multiple submit buttons, the only real option without Javascript is to use the `name` as shown. Remember the `value` is displayed on screen so is not feasible to store IDs there.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. I will give your technique a try and see how it goes. If i use your second example using the delete_(ID) as name is this method a fast and reliable way of processing the request?

Comment: Yes both methods are fast and reliable for what you're doing.

Comment: I cant seem to get the code you provided working. I have set up the code exaclty as you have it shown above however when i add echo $id; into the if statement under $id = substr($key, 7); when i click on any of the buttons no id is displayed.

Comment: There was a syntax error in my answer on the `strpos()` line. I've fixed it. Have another go...

Comment: using a name like 'delete[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]' would be somewhat easier.